# TYPO3 11.5 LTS - SEO: XML sitemap in not showing pages

Tags: typo3-11.x

TYPO3 11.5.25

I’m trying to use SEO in order to create a XML sitemap of my site (multidomain), but it doesn’t show any page.

http://example.org/?type=1533906435

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <sitemap>
    <loc>http://example.org/?sitemap=pages&amp;type=1533906435&amp;Hash=86d19fe655189d9dafc81c77d4448f6a
    </loc>
  <lastmod>2023-10-04T07:37:56-05:00</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

I installed the extension typo3/cms-seo, configured my sites in “Sites” module, included “XML sitemap” to the template in main page (uid 1) and added the following TypoScript in my template:

```
plugin.tx_seo {
  config {
    xmlSitemap {
      sitemaps {
        pages {
          provider = TYPO3\CMS\Seo\XmlSitemap\PagesXmlSitemapDataProvider
          config {
            excludedDoktypes = 3, 4, 6, 7, 199, 254, 255
            additionalWhere = no_index = 0
          }
        }
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

I don’t know what I’m doing wrong… I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to adjust your site configuration in your yaml-file (typo3conf/sites ...

with something like that

### routes:

```
route: sitemap.xml
type: uri
source: 't3://page?uid=1' (id of the page that should be the root of the sitemap)
```

websiteTitle: 'my website'

By the way: Use Chorme or Edge to show up the sitemap (doesn't work with firefox). As far as I remember, the sitemap isn't build if config.no_cache = 1 in your setup is set.